# I think Facebook blacklisted my son

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Approximately two months ago, my son's Facebook account was disabled for using a fake name. He made a fake account and was trolling various people/political sites and their comments sections.

I was under the impression that Facebook normally bans people who engage in this type of behavior for a month; however his account has now been banned for two months and counting. Additionally, he has attempted to create new accounts with different email addresses (with his real name this time), yet, after 15-20 minutes, Facebook disables his account "as a security precaution" and asks that he upload a photo ID. It's almost as if he has been permanently flagged/blacklisted from even opening a new account.

Can anyone please help me find a solution to this? I have searched and searched, but don't know what to do. What he did was idiotic and unnecessary, however I think being banned for two months as well as being blacklisted is a bit harsh.

Answer (score 5):

He has to [submit his ID proof](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/183000765122339) to get back real account. He can provide any ID proof which is having his real name, date of birth and a color photograph. Other sensitive data can be blurred. If they find it Ok, he will get his account back.

Now days Facebook is very strict about their policies and security. One must follow to their [Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards).